# encoding specified in XML declaration is incorrect error keep occurring

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I am working with data from drug bank which is in XML format.
I try to parse drug name and its mechanisms, but my program keeps throwing the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\erttll\workspace\drugbank_parsing\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    tree = parse("drugbank.xml")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 656, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1642, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: encoding specified in XML declaration is incorrect: line 1, column 31
```

I do not know why this is happening. The encoding of the document is UTF-8.

Here is my code:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = parse("drugbank.xml")
    root = tree.getroot()
    for drug in root.iter("drug"):
        if drug != None:
            drug_name = drug.findtext("name")
            parmacodynamics = drug.findtext("pharmacodynamics")
            MOA = drug.findtext("mechanism-of-action")
            MOA_result = open(".\MOA_result\%s.txt"%drug_name,"w")
            MOA_result.write(parmacodynamics + MOA)

        else:
            continue
```

plus: XML header is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: There are easier ways to parse xml files: BeautifulSoup (probably the best option, but you have to install the module), minidom (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2qlCZhkwtE) - this one is included in Python 2.75 build. If you can show us the xml file, we can help with the actual code

Comment: @Kruger Thank you for suggestion!! I'll try to use BeautifulSoup. I wish I could show XML file to you, but it is too large to upload. I'm sorry.

Comment: Try add this to your file `import sys
reload(sys).setdefaultencoding('utf8')`

Comment: @luoluo I have tried that way, but it did not work. sorry about that